# Jersey: How to register MultiPartConfigProvider class

Tags: exception, multipart, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to load multiple files with jersey, but it demands me some configuration that i can't find. 
This is the dependency, I had to add it because jersey couldn't resolver the type "multipart/related":

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

This is the API where I use the multipart:

```
    @PUT
    @Consumes("multipart/related")
    @Path("/{id}/user/{userId}")
    public Response loadFile(@PathParam("id") int id, @PathParam("userId") int userId, MultiPart files) throws Exception{
        int resultado = tool.loadFile(id, userId, files);
        switch (resultado){
        case 401:   return Response.status(401).entity("No existe el experimento con id: "+id).build();
        case 402:   return Response.status(402).entity("El tipo de uno de los archivos no se encuentra en los tipos de entregables del experimento").build();
        case 403:   return Response.status(403).entity("El usuario: "+userId+" no participa en el experimento").build();
        case 405:   return Response.status(405).entity("Debe ingresar un comentario").build();
        case 406:   return Response.status(406).entity("Hay entregables sin subir").build();
        case 200:   return Response.status(200).build();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the web.xml, I think I am missing something here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.mockapi</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is the exception:

```
A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The MultiPartConfig instance we expected is not present.  Have you registered the MultiPartConfigProvider class?
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are using new version of dropwizard, then the dependency should be,

    `<dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
         <version>2.15</version>
     </dependency>`

Because new version of `dropwizard` uses `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar`.
And we have to register `MultiPartFeature` in our Application's `run` method as
   `environment.jersey().register(MultiPartFeature.class);`
For more information you can check [here](http://blog.remmelt.com/2015/02/02/file-upload-using-dropwizard-0-8-0-rc2/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this on your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

It fix my problem, and I hope it