# Handle "multipart/related" in java servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets, jetty

A Servlet, running under Jetty 8, receives the following request:

```
Header:
Content-Type = multipart/related; boundary=example

Data:

--example
content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8

data1here

--example
content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8

data2here

--example--
```

- Is there a convenient way of getting "data1here" and "data2here" from this kind of a request?
- Do Java servlets support it, natively?
- Or are there any additional libraries that support it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Consumes Annotation

[Consume](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html#JAX-RSMultiparts-Formsandmultiparts) the event using a JAX-RS annotation provided by [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/):

```
@Consumes("multipart/related")
```

From the JAX-RS documentation:

> It is now possible (since 2.2.5) to have individual `multipart/form-data` parts read by registered JAX-RS MessageBodyReaders, something that is already possible to do for types like `multipart/mixed` or `multipart/related`.

See also:

- [Spring boot multipart/related mime type support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38838926/59087)
- [Jersey: How to register MultiPartConfigProvider class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23982065/59087)

Note that Jersey, which is used by GlassFish, has no mention of `related` in its [source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/media/multipart/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartMediaTypes.java).

## HTTP Client

Google offers an [API](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-http-client/latest/com.google.api.client.http.MultipartContent) for an [HTTP client](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-http-client/latest/overview) that parses `multipart/related` messages as per the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521#section-7.2.2).

## RESTeasy

The [RESTeasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) project can parse [`multipart/related`](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/#MultipartRelated) content via JAX-RS.

## JavaMail API

With some stream contortions, it may be possible to use the JavaMail API to parse a [MimeMultipart](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html) message:

> The default multipart subtype is "mixed". The other multipart subtypes, such as "alternative", "related", and so on, can be implemented as subclasses of MimeMultipart with additional methods to implement the additional semantics of that type of multipart content.

The [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ) offers a few more details:

> As described above, there are more complex cases to consider as well. In particular, messages may have arbitrary nesting of `multipart/mixed` and `multipart/alternative` parts and may include `multipart/related` parts for embedded HTML and `multipart/signed` and/or `multipart/encrypted` parts for secure messages.

I'd advise against this approach because it mixes metaphors (it conflates MIME over HTTP/web with MIME over SMTP/mail). That is, JavaMail, conceptually, is used for reading and writing messages over SMTP/IMAP, which could leave future maintainers wondering why JavaMail is being used to parse MIME messages received via Servlets, especially when there are annotation-based solutions available. That said, documenting the code with the reason for its usage would be a way to avoid any confusion.

## Container

Depending on the container, it may or may not handle all pertinent RFCs. You may have to try (or peruse the source code of) different containers to see what ones implement this feature.

### Jetty

The [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project) has a few spots related to parsing input streams, which are limited to `multipart/form-data`:

- [MultiPartFilter](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/71d5fcf246034dce91cd642d35cdbaace9806329/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/MultiPartFilter.java#L146)
- [MultiPartInputStreamParser](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/71d5fcf246034dce91cd642d35cdbaace9806329/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/MultiPartInputStreamParser.java#L505)

Additionally, the [unit tests](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/71d5fcf246034dce91cd642d35cdbaace9806329/tests/test-integration/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/test/rfcs) do not include [RFC 2387](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387), which is a strong indicator that the container does not handle `related` parts under the Servlet 3.0 API. As such, JAX-RS is probably the best approach.

### Tomcat

Tomcat has [not implemented](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54917) `multipart/related` as part of the Servlet 3.0 specification, although there exists a patched version of Tomcat 7.0.47 that does.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the JavaMail library and read the data in as "mail". You end up with a MimeMessage and can go through the BodyParts for processing. Usage is quite straight forward, I used this approach to implement an AS2 server and I've seen other implementations of AS2 doing the same, so it's a quite common approach.

I don't see a conflict of standards here. The whole request format is MIME, so handling it by a library intended for processing MIME encoded messages is in my eyes a correct way of handling things.

Comment: This answer does not add anything new on top of the already given answer. It seems to be posted merely for sake of points.