# Servlet 3.0 MultiPartConfig not working for multipart/related

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I am getting the following exception when trying to use the `getParts()` method on the `HttpServletRequest` Object. Here is the `request#contentType() = "multipart/related; type="application/dicom"; boundary=multiparttest"`

```
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010016: Not a multi part request
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.loadParts(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:575)
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)     at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParts(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:514)
```

Almost all of the documentation talks about multipart/form-data. Is multipart/related not supported by `MultiPartConfig`? What is the best way to procress request with multipart/related content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle "multipart/related" in java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022763/handle-multipart-related-in-java-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet should looks like:

```
@WebServlet("/upload")
@MultipartConfig(location = "C:/temp", 
        fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 1, // 1 MB
        maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10, // 10 MB
        maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 15 // 15 MB
)
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
//your code here
}
```

I found this from the post [Servlet 3 File Upload Example using MultipartConfig](http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/servlet-jsp/servlet-3-file-upload-example-using-multipartconfig.html)

Other way:

Referred to the Spring documentation on JAX-RS and chose to use the Jersey dependency that support multipart/related to solve it. I found the following test project: https://github.com/ShawnTuatara/stackoverflow-38838926.

Comment: I did the same. As mentioned in my questions, the exception I am getting is the request is not multipart. So, I am guessing, 'multipart/related' content type is not recognized as multipart by the servlet. I am wondering what would be the best way to parse the HttpsServletRequest parts; if there are any libraries that support 'multipart/related'.